# itext in java,cann't use PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

Tags: java, itext

i'm trying to print a bar-code into a pdf,but when i type writer..getDirectContent(); it shows an error.

i imported the following

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException; 
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph; 
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BarcodeEAN;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
```

**My code**from a result set i'm to print the bar-code in a pdf

```
try{
    String sel_peince=jTextField33.getText();
    String des=jTextField29.getText();
    if((sel_peince.compareTo("")!=0)  && (des.compareTo("")!=0)){
    String sql="Select * from printing_press_inventory where unit_selling_price='"+sel_peince+"' and description ='"+des+"'";
                    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);

                    rs.next();
                    String oitm=""+rs.getInt("item_id");
                    String Oqt=""+rs.getInt("quantity");
                    String description=rs.getString("description");


        Document doc=new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("Barcode.pdf"));
        doc.open();
        doc.add(new Paragraph(new Chunk("Barcode for "+description+"")));

      PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
       BarcodeEAN codeEAN=new BarcodeEAN();
       codeEAN.setCode(oitm);
       Paragraph p=new Paragraph();
       codeEAN.setCodeType(BarcodeEAN.UPCA);
       doc.add(codeEAN.createImageWithBarcode(null, BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.BLACK));
       doc.add(p);
         doc.close();
}
    else{
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "eerrrrr");  
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

THANK you !:D

Answer (score 0):

thank you guy,i found a way...:D :D 
i **imported** the following

```
> import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor; import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
> import com.itextpdf.text.Document; import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
> import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize; import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
> import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase; import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.Barcode;
> import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BarcodeEAN; import
> com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte; import
> com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

and **code** is

```
> 
> Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
>         try {
>             PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("BarcodesEAN13.pdf"));
>             document.open();
>             PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
>             
>             BarcodeEAN codeEAN = new BarcodeEAN();
>             codeEAN.setCodeType(Barcode.EAN13);
>             codeEAN.setCode("1234567812345");
>             Image imageEAN = codeEAN.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
> 
>             document.add(new Phrase(new Chunk(imageEAN, 0, 0)));
>         }
>         catch (Exception de) {
>             de.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         document.close();
```